# Curl: No route to host via ipv4 but works with ipv6

Tags: networking, wifi, curl

I can curl with ipv6 succesfully but not with ipv4.

```
> curl -4 icanhazip.com
curl: (7) Failed to connect to icanhazip.com port 80: No route to host
```

But with ipv6 it's successful

```
> curl icanhazip.com
2601:681:5100:3e07::7bd4
```

I have [raspap-webgui](https://github.com/billz/raspap-webgui) installed using a static IP on Raspian Stretch Lite on a Raspberry Pi Zero W.

ifconfig:

```
    lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 400  bytes 32109 (31.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 400  bytes 32109 (31.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

usb0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 169.254.242.203  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 169.254.255.255
        inet6 fe80::afaa:427d:2758:6d5d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:c5:01:98:ad:d0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1103  bytes 138145 (134.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 638  bytes 97092 (94.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.3.141.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.3.141.255
        inet6 2601:681:5100:3e07::7bd4  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::4ffd:94d1:1cc0:5b60  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2601:681:5100:3e07:556b:6800:413a:5ded  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether b8:27:eb:a4:80:7e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 529  bytes 74655 (72.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 226  bytes 27286 (26.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Route Tables:

```
> route -A inet
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.3.141.1      0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0
10.3.141.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     202    0        0 usb0

> route -A inet6
Kernel IPv6 routing table
Destination                    Next Hop                   Flag Met Ref Use If
2601:681:5100:3e07::/64        [::]                       U    303 1     0 wlan0
fe80::/64                      [::]                       U    256 2     9 usb0
fe80::/64                      [::]                       U    256 1     0 wlan0
[::]/0                         fe80::250:f1ff:fe80:0      UG   303 2    76 wlan0
[::]/0                         [::]                       !n   -1  1    86 lo
localhost/128                  [::]                       Un   0   3     3 lo
2601:681:5100:3e07::7bd4/128   [::]                       Un   0   3    43 wlan0
2601:681:5100:3e07:556b:6800:413a:5ded/128 [::]                       Un   0   2     0 wlan0
fe80::4ffd:94d1:1cc0:5b60/128  [::]                       Un   0   3    15 wlan0
fe80::afaa:427d:2758:6d5d/128  [::]                       Un   0   3    16 usb0
ff00::/8                       [::]                       U    256 2    54 usb0
ff00::/8                       [::]                       U    256 2   297 wlan0
[::]/0                         [::]                       !n   -1  1    89 lo
```

Edit:

```
> systemd-resolve --status
Global
         DNS Servers: 1.1.1.1
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 3 (wlan0)
      Current Scopes: LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 2 (usb0)
      Current Scopes: none
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
```

dig

```
> dig -t A icanhazip.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Raspbian <<>> -t A icanhazip.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 10101
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;icanhazip.com.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
icanhazip.com.      300 IN  A   147.75.89.25
icanhazip.com.      300 IN  A   147.75.96.57
icanhazip.com.      300 IN  A   147.75.92.157

;; Query time: 23 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Mar 21 22:38:40 GMT 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 90
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is with DNS returning some invalid address? What does `dig -t A icanhazip.com` show? What about `systemd-resolve --status`?

Comment: Edited question with output

Comment: What happens for `curl -4 147.75.89.25`? (That's the IP for the site that you're trying to hit, so it bypasses DNS issues.)

Comment: @Brick same issue

Comment: I suggest that you take the question to https://serverfault.com/ instead.  Looks like there's nothing here related to the Pi it's really looking like a networking question.

Comment: Is you Pi set to be the gateway? Your `ifconfig` seems to show that your Pi has IP 10.3.141.1 over `wlan0` but that is also the default gateway shown by `route`.